# How do you find the value of the ratio in a series?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

The sum of the geometric series $a,ar,ar^2,\dots,ar^{n-1}$ is $$s=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$ Given $a,s,n,r$ we can easily solve for $a,s,n$. But how can we solve for $r$ in terms of $a,s,n$? Also $r$ will always be between    -1 and 1 What method should I use to find $r$ and how does the method work?

Comment: What is r?  What are the other variables?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer. Please check it is still what you want.

Comment: its about right thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $n \leq 5$ there are formulas to solve this, though the one for $n=5$ is a mess.  For larger $n$ you are in for a numeric solution.  I find fixed point iteration handy.  For many values of $a,s,n$ you could write $$r_{i+1}=\sqrt[n]{\frac sa(r_i-1)+1}$$ because roots do not change too much.  If $n$ is large and $r \gt 1$ the last term will dominate, so I would ignore all the early terms in the sum and try $r_0=\sqrt[n-1]{\frac sa}$

Comment: Can you give example when plugging in values please.